# Is there a C/C++ API for Tensorflow object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Is there a C/C++ API, pre-trained with Imagenet dataset, for Detection ?

I have tried Yolo, with
./darknet -i 0 detector demo cfg/imagenet1k.data extraction.cfg  extraction.weights

But it gives me the error
Last layer must produce detections

And for Tensorflow, looks like there is only python API
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Answer (score 1):

When you develop a model in TensorFlow, it can be output as a protobuf file (usually with a pb extension, for more details on protobuf in TensorFlow [check out this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/)). This protobuf file can then be used in different applications written in languages that TensorFlow has bindings to. [A simple tutorial on how to accomplish this for a C++ application can be found here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_recognition)

Regarding Yolo, you can generate a protobuf file from the Yolo script like this:

```
flow --model cfg/yolo.cfg --load bin/yolo.weights --savepb
```

(Further details on other parameters that can be passed to Yolo can be found on [the Github readme page](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow)).

The output protobuf file can then be loaded into your C++ application to perform object detection.